# How to make Kendo Grid's Read event more efficient

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When I capture Kendo Grid's read traffic, I can see that it receives just enough data for the current page. So if the page size is 5, just five item will be transmitted.

With this in mind, is there any point for filtering data in the action method? Like using `take` and `skip` Linq commands, or `ToDataSourceResult` extension method will take care of everything?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your result is of type `IQueryable<T>`, the `ToDataSourceResult()` will defer execution to the database level (assuming you are using EntityFramework or similar ORMs) to take care of pagination, filtering and sorting.

You can read more about it here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding (there is a callout to this specific functionality in yellow after step 10)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's good to limit the data your LINQ selects to the columns your grid contains, and have it return an `IQueryable`. Generally you don't need to do anything else, except call `ToDataSourceResult`. It handles server-side filtering, paging, and sorting.

If you want to do anything in addition to that, you can extend it.

See [KendoUI: Understanding ToDataSourceResult](https://doylestowncoder.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/kendoui-understanding-todatasourceresult/)